# Is it possible to check if a canavs item has an outline in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to make some code that will check if a canvas item has an outline. If it does, nothing will happen, if it doesn't, it will give it one. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please provide a [mre]

Comment: Have you tried using `<tkinter.Canvas>.itemcget(<id or tag>, "outline")`?

Comment: FYI, I got that from [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2012-November/092795.html). But in that case they used `.itemcget(<id or tag>, "fill")`.